# How to find distance beetwen two objects in libgdx

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx

In my LibGdx game i have waypoins(ModelInstance) and i need to know the distance beetwen them.
I tryed to use **Transform.getTranslation(new Vector3)** but it returns the translation of model. I have't found methods to get Global position of model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the distance between two vectors use the dst method:

```
public float dst(Vector3 vector)
Specified by:
dst in interface Vector<Vector3>
Parameters:
vector - The other vector
Returns:
the distance between this and the other vector
```

[Vector3 reference](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html)

The best way to track your model is create a wrapper that stores your object position (Vector3) and rotation (Quaternion) and in this wrapper set the model position on your render method, something like this:

```
public abstract class ModelWrapper{

    private ModelInstance model;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Quaternion rotation;

    public ModelWrapper(ModelInstance model,Vector3 position,Quaternion rotation) {
        this.model = model;
        this.position = position;
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public ModelInstance getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(ModelInstance model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Vector3 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector3 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Quaternion getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(Quaternion rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public void render(ModelBatch modelBatch, Environment  environment) {
        this.model.transform.set(this.position,this.rotation);
        modelBatch.render(model, environment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good, it will really help me. And how to get position of model in global space?

Comment: your ModelWrapper instance .getPosition()

Answer (score 2):

Your game in 2D or in 3D space?
If in 2D, then we can simply use the Pythagorean theorem and write our own method:

```
double distance(Vector2 object1, Vector2 object2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((object2.x - object1.x), 2) + Math.pow((object2.y - object1.y), 2));
}
```

Comment: There is a Vector2.dst(x1, y1, x2, y2) method.